# How to featch data, in which state session is end in joomla 2.5?

Tags: session, joomla2.5, session-state, virtuemart

Hi I am working on abandoned cart module in joomla 2.5.8 store which i developed with help of virtuemart 2.0.14.

Now I am able to find some related data from the joomla's session table but i am not able to find in which stage session is expire (eg. has user close browser or quit at 1st step of checkout or has user quit or close browser before checkout process)I mean user state at the closing or quit browser.

So please help me or guide me to fetch user state when he/she had quite or close the browser.

Comment: http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_access_session_variables_set_by_an_external_script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way you can find whether user closes browser or not closed using session data. Session data is stored on your server and will expire as per your server session expire settings.

If you would really like to know user browser closing status, you need to write some special javascript function to detect when browser is being closed, and call server an ajax request to expire the session or some other function.

Comment: thanks for your reply... I implement javascript windows.onbeforeunload but problem in this is it not only prompt when i close the browser/close tab but also every time when page is unload and windows.onclose or closed or close() is not working...

Answer (score 1):

You need some code that do something like this:

```
private static function unserializeSession($session_data) {
    try{
        $method = ini_get("session.serialize_handler");
        $dataArr = array();
        switch ($method) {
            case "php":
                $dataArr =  self::unserialize_php($session_data);
                break;
            case "php_binary":
                $dataArr = self::unserialize_phpbinary($session_data);
                break;
            default:

                $dataArr = false;
        }
        return $dataArr;
    }
    catch (Exception $e){

        return false;
    }
}
```

However, you should not bother to develop such module. There are many 3rd party solution like [Remarkety](http://www.remarkety.com) or [Interamind](http://www.interamind.com) that solve this for you for you.

Take care,